# Show that an exponential rv is sub-exponential

Tags: probability, inequality, taylor-expansion

Let $X \sim Exp(1/\mu)$ for some $\mu>0$ be an exponential random variable.

Recall that a random variable is subexponential if there is a $\sigma> 0$ such that it's moment generating function has the following property for all $\lambda$ in an neighborhood of $0$.

$$\mathbb E\left [ e^{\lambda X} \right ] \leq e^{\lambda^2\sigma^2/2}$$

Find a $\sigma$ and a neighborhood of $0$ such that the above is true.

**my attempt**

First, let's compute the MGF of $X$:

$$\mathbb E [ \exp(\lambda X)] = e^{-\lambda\mu}/(1-\lambda\mu)$$

So we must find a value of $\sigma$ such that:

$$e^{\lambda^2\sigma^2/2+\lambda\mu}\geq\frac{1}{1-\mu\lambda}$$

Taking the log of both sides:

$$\lambda^2\sigma^2/2+\lambda\mu\geq-\log{1-\mu\lambda}$$

Taking a taylor expansion of the RHS around $0$:

$$-\log{1-\mu\lambda} = - \left(-\mu\lambda - \frac{1}{(1-\hat x)^2}\frac{(\mu\lambda)^2}{2}\right)$$

for some $\hat x \in [0, \mu\lambda]$. Collecting these terms onto the LHS, we need to show:

$$\lambda^2\sigma^2/2+\lambda\mu + -\mu\lambda - \frac{1}{(1-\hat x)^2}\frac{(\mu\lambda)^2}{2} \geq 0$$

The last term is decreasing with $\hat x$, so if we restrict $\lambda$ to the interval such that $|\lambda| \leq 1/(2\mu)$ then $\sigma > 2\mu$ is sufficient. $\square$

I would expect that the best $\sigma$ is $\mu$, so I wonder if I have made a mistake in my derivation. If I haven't, I could use some tips on how to obtain a better (smaller) $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $-\ln( 1- \lambda \mu ) \le \frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2} +\lambda \mu$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Besides, $-\ln( 1- \lambda \mu )= \lambda\mu+\frac{ (\lambda\mu)^2}{2}+\frac{(\lambda\mu)^3}{3}+O(\lambda^4)$. Hence, your conclusion is true for $\sigma$ strictly bigger than $\mu$, while being false for  $\sigma \le \mu$ .

Comment: Got it, thanks! So we cannot achieve the $\sigma$ that I expected. And to get close to it, we have to restrict $\lambda$ to a small interval

Comment: @dmh: Yes. That's it.